# Out of the box Ubuntu 13.04 with Chromium does not automatically use web apps

Tags: chromium, 13.04, webapps

I really like the web apps feature in Ubuntu, but when I installed Ubuntu 13.04 and cChromium the automatic integration didn't work. I have no idea how to kick-start the integration.

Anyone an idea?

Comment: i have the same problem. When i use Firefox i get the pop up massage but with chromium nothing happens, even if the option notify me if the website can run as application is checked.

Answer (score 2):

A extra package needs to be installed to enable web apps functionality in Chromium.

Search for **unity-chromium-extension** in the Software Center or run the following from the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-chromium-extension
```

Now if only it would work in Chrome too...